# Running Spawn/Expect to Join Active Directory

Tags: bash, expect

Not quite sure if this is the right forum to ask this question. But I do see a lot of questions specific to using expect/spawn/send, so here it goes. I am building a bash script to join an Active Directory Domain. When I try executing the script I get this error:

```
spawn realm join --user="foouser@foo.local" --computer-ou="OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local" FOO.LOCAL
realm: Specify one realm to join
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "foobarpassword\r""
```

I'm not sure why realm is complaining about seeing multiple realms But here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ad_user="foouser@foo.local"
ad_password="bar"
ad_ou="OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local"
ad_domain="FOO.LOCAL"

expect <<-EOD
     spawn realm join --user="$ad_user" --computer-ou="$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
     expect "Password for foouser@foo.local:"
     send "$ad_password\r"
     interact
EOD
```

Can someone please tell me what could cause realm to complain about multiple domains? And why expect is not working?

Update: I added more verbosity to the script and get this error message:

```
spawn realm join --user="foouser@FOO.LOCAL" --computer-ou="OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local" FOO.LOCAL
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {883}
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'Password for foouser@FOO.LOCAL: ' is 'Password for foouser@FOO?LOCAL: '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "Password for foouser@FOO.LOCAL: "? Gate "Password for foouser@FOO?LOCAL: "? gate=no
realm: Specify one realm to join

    expect: does "realm: Specify one realm to join\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "Password for foouser@FOO.LOCAL: "? Gate "Password for foouser@FOO?LOCAL: "? gate=no
    expect: read eof
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
    expect: set expect_out(buffer) "realm: Specify one realm to join\r\n"
    send: sending "bar\n" to { exp6 send: spawn id exp6 not open
        while executing
    "send -- "bar\n""
```

Comment: `$FOO=bar` is not a valid assignment in bash. It needs to be `FOO=bar` (and really, to be compliant with POSIX-specified conventions, should be `foo=bar`; all-caps names are reserved for variables meaningful to the OS or system).

Comment: Whoops.. Sorry let me fix that..

Comment: ...beyond that -- the approach you're using here is passing your shell variables into expect in a context wherein they can be parsed as syntax. If you're ever letting someone you don't trust provide part of the input (say, the password?), that would be Very Bad News. Much safer to pass values out-of-band from code -- say, in the environment, and then have the expect code refer to environment variables when it needs them.

Comment: This is not the exact script and Im not hard coding the password in my actual script. The code snippet is very similar to what im trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you have any recommendations on what may need to be fixed for this script? Just note, this is not the exact script that im using and the real focus is to get expect to work correctly.

Comment: It looks like the realm command is exiting before you get to the send command. Add `exp_internal 1` to the expect code before you spawn, and see if the extra debugging output helps you figure out what's going on. The "realm: Specify one realm to join" error message might give you a clue -- doesn't look like you're invoking the command with the proper arguments.

Comment: @glennjackman i updated my question with the output.

Comment: Am i asking in the wrong forum? I dont seem to be getting responses to the suggestions that are being made....

Comment: This question is only, what, an hour old? Particularly when you need specialized knowledge, expect to wait a while -- different people come in and out of availability at different times of day. The extra debugging info you added is helpful, but regardless, you should be willing to wait a few days. And BTW, the original approach where you were spawning `realm join` from *inside* `expect` was correct, insofar as that order-of-operations is concerned. Putting `expect` after `realm join` is clearly wrong.

Comment: ...to be clear on that point, `send` sends data *to something that `expect` spawned*. If `expect` didn't start the `realm` command, it doesn't have its stdin and stdout handles, so can't send data to it or read data from it.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thanks

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: @pynexj, have you evaluated that against [EmPTY](http://empty.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `empty` lacks so many features. e.g. it cannot `spawn date; expect eof`; it cannot get exit code of the forked process; it cannot match against patterns (glob or RE); it does not support `interact` (attaching to the forked process); ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@komar's answer got me thinking about they quotes. Tcl quotes are only special when they are the *first character of the word* (ref: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm, rules 4 and 6).

For example, consider this interactive tclsh session:

```
% proc spawn args {puts $args}
% set ad_user     "foouser@foo.local"
foouser@foo.local
% set ad_password "bar"
bar
% set ad_ou       "OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local"
OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local
+% set ad_domain   "FOO.LOCAL"
FOO.LOCAL
%
% spawn realm join --user="$ad_user" --computer-ou="$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
realm join --user=\"foouser@foo.local\" {--computer-ou="OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local"} FOO.LOCAL
```

Note how the double quotes are protected. That indicates you are sending literal double quotes to the `realm` command.

So try this: change

```
 spawn realm join --user="$ad_user" --computer-ou="$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
 # ......................^........................^
```

to

```
 spawn realm join "--user=$ad_user" "--computer-ou=$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
 # ...............^.................^
```

Comment: This is a really helpful insight about the way those quotes are handled in expect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `ad_ou="OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local"` consist space.
When you use it in bash's "Here Documents" <<- feature, it's will generate expect script without "" quite. Bash code:

```
spawn realm join --user="$ad_user" --computer-ou="$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
```

Will be generating to expect code

```
spawn realm join --user=foouser@foo.local --computer-ou=OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local FOO.LOCAL
```

Which ok for expect, but as I say your variable consist space.
You need quote in expect. There is two way:

```
    spawn realm join --user=\""$ad_user"\" --computer-ou=\""$ad_ou"\" \""$ad_domain"\"
```

Or you can use expect strict quoting with {}:

```
spawn realm join --user={"$ad_user"} --computer-ou={"$ad_ou"} {"$ad_domain"}
```

PS: Also you can write it as expect script, without bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ad_user     "foouser@foo.local"
set ad_password "bar"
set ad_ou       "OU=Foo,OU=Foo Servers,DC=foo,DC=local"
set ad_domain   "FOO.LOCAL"

spawn realm join --user="$ad_user" --computer-ou="$ad_ou" "$ad_domain"
expect "Password for $ad_user:"
send "$ad_password\r"
interact
```

Comment: here-docs do **not** remove double quotes. Replace the OP's `expect <<-EOD` with `cat <<-EOD` to confirm.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It comes up with a different error message: `realm: No such realm found`

Comment: Also, braces are only special in Tcl as the *first* character of a word (https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10)

Comment: You are right. So like this?: `spawn realm join {--user=$ad_user} {--computer-ou=$ad_ou} {$ad_domain}`

Comment: yes. The shell will expand the variables in the here-doc before sending the contents of the here-doc to expect. Then, expect will receive the nicely brace-quoted arguments.