# Realm fails when running from Ansible on RHEL 7.9

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate joining Linux servcers to an AD domain using Ansible. I have pretty much gotten everything to worek except the actual join. Because this is RHEL7 the Ansible module `ansible.builtin.expect` does not work because RHEL7 has only pexpect2.6 and Ansible expects it to be 3.3 or hiugher. After hunting all over I found this using Linux expect:

```
shell: |
    set timeout 300

    spawn /usr/sbin/realm join -v --user=Administrator --computer-ou="OU=Linux,OU=Servers," --os-name={{ ansible_distribution }} --os-version={{ ansible_distribution_version }} my.domain.com

    expect "Password for * "
    send "{{ bind_password }}"

    expect "* Successfully enrolled machine in realm"
    send "\n"
    exit 0
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
  when: realmd_bound.failed
```

This fails with `"realm: Specify one realm to join"` even though I put in a realm. I tried the command from the test target and the command executed correctly.

What is Ansible doing that is different from a regular command line and how do I correct it?

EDIT:

I tried putting the realm discover in line with the realm join

```
realm discover my.domain.com && realm join --user=admin@my.domain.com --computer-ou="OU=Linux,OU=Servers," --os-name={{ ansible_distribution }} --os-version={{ ansible_distribution_version }} my.domain.com
```

and now I get:

```
"realm: Unknown option --user=admin@my.domain.com"
```

Additonal troubleshooting:

I tried the script. However I got the same error. after further research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808386/running-spawn-expect-to-join-active-directory)to be helpful. I entered in the quotes where they were suggested to go and I got stopped at a new location. Our administrator accounts have a "$" in them. Before I get flooded by a ton of "This is Linux! You should never use a $ in a name! $ is SPECIAL!!!" I know but this is a Windows shop long before Linux started creeping in. And, as you know, Windows treats damn few things as special.

That being said I now get  "can't read "amp": no such variable". the admin id ends in $amp thus it cannot read the variable $amp. When I use the survey to input the user ID I use a $ combination and I get user$amp sent as the command. realm then interprets it as user(vaule of amp variable). I have tried \$ so it will put in $ in the command but all it does is put in \\$ and it still dosn not run.

I cannot avoid using the $.

Let me know if I need to put this section in a question all of its own.

Comment: FWIW, try [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#ansible-builtin-script-runs-a-local-script-on-a-remote-node-after-transferring-it), i.e. create working script the use it in Ansible.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I may have to as a last resort. I am just uncertain how to find out errors in the script. since there is no return error description.

Comment: block/rescue might help you to debug the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us how this related to the Realm tag? Realm is part of MongoDB Realm - the database.

Comment: My bad. I am refering to the realm Linux command. I saw the tag and was unaware there is a MongoDB realm.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**How to find out errors in the script. Since there is no return error description.**"*

A: The dictionary *ansible_failed_result* is always available in failed [block/rescue](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - shell: /usr/bin/false
      rescue:
        - debug:
            var: ansible_failed_result
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [shell] ***************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd: /usr/bin/false
  delta: '0:00:00.004537'
  end: '2021-08-15 14:23:20.533469'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2021-08-15 14:23:20.528932'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_failed_result:
    changed: true
    cmd: /usr/bin/false
    delta: '0:00:00.004537'
    end: '2021-08-15 14:23:20.533469'
    failed: true
    invocation:
      module_args:
        _raw_params: /usr/bin/false
        _uses_shell: true
        argv: null
        chdir: null
        creates: null
        executable: null
        removes: null
        stdin: null
        stdin_add_newline: true
        strip_empty_ends: true
        warn: true
    msg: non-zero return code
    rc: 1
    start: '2021-08-15 14:23:20.528932'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
```